# Calculate point coordinates having angle and length in 2d

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I am having a little geometry problem to solve and I have to say that my math is a little rusty. I've attached an image below, which explain visually my situation.

[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk8IK.jpg)

I have the following information, coordinates of points W and Z, length of WA = AB = BZ and length WZ. I have the angle θ as well.

My question is, how can I calculate coordinates of points A and B?

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share some of your approaches?

Comment: I've used transpositional formulae given the length between two points and Wx,Wy and Ax trying to find Ay but did not work because I don't have the right value of Ax. I did not include it because is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot comment yet, but if you have to do such an operation more often, I would look into Rotation matrices. It will be beneficial in the future.

For now, can you calculate the length of $ZW$?

Comment: Hi @WalterJ yes I have the length ZW because I have the coordinates of W and Z

Comment: Then I suppose you should be able to find $ZB$ and $ZA$, assuming your grid is nicely spaced. Once you have those lengths, finding the coordinates is a matter of applying cos() and sin(). 

If this is confusing, think about rotating your frame back and then finding those lengths.